# Python 3.2 Idle vs terminal

Tags: python, python-idle

In python 3.2 under OSX, if I'll run "type(sys.stdin)" under Idle I get a strange answer as shown below

```
>>> type(sys.stdin)
<class 'idlelib.rpc.RPCProxy'>
>>>
```

But if I'll reun the same command under terminal, I get:

```
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys.stdin)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>>
```

I understand this is because I'm running it under IDLE. but is this not misleading?

I was trying to run the following commands in IDLE and spent hours trying to understand as to why this is not working. (I'm still a python noob)

```
>>> w = sys.stdin.readlines()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    w = sys.stdin.readlines()
AttributeError: readlines
```

But just discovered that I works fine under terminal.

```
>>> w = sys.stdin.readlines()
wow
ww
wewew
>>> 
>>> w
['wow\n', 'ww\n', 'wewew\n']
>>>
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: The work-aorund is to use `w = list(sys.stdin)`, which will always work.  And I think it is a bug -- `sys.stdin` should implement the interface of `io.IOBase`.

Comment: This also happens in Python 2.7

Comment: It happens in all versions of IDLE, at least since readlines has been introduced.  Unfortunately, as the open bug cited below points out, IDLE's implementations of `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` proxies are not complete and up-to-date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a filed Python bug:

http://bugs.python.org/issue9290

> The fact that in IDLE sys.stdin is a
>   `idlelib.rpc.RPCProxy` results in
>   programs having different behavior in
>   IDLE and in Command Line mode.
>
> I noticed that when grading many
>   students exercises in IDLE. Things
>   like:
>
> ```
> sys.stdin.readlines()
> ```
>
> just don´t exists in IDLE, but are
>   fully operational in Command Line
>   mode.
>
> In Command Line mode, sys.stdin is a
>   file.
>
> This is expected, as the manual (27.1)
>   says that sys.stdin (and stdout and
>   stderrr) are "File objects
>   corresponding to the interpreter’s
>   standard input"
>
> There are also other "quirks".
>
> I fell that is really strange that
>   stdin has different behavior for the
>   same program.

---

Note that this is probably not fixed because `readlines` is not normally useful. Instead, you can just iterate over the file objects itself:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ...
```