# readline() reads all data including '\n'

Tags: python, input

```
import sys

n = int(sys.stdin.readline())

for _ in range(n):
   s = input()
   print(s)
```

This is my code in Python3.3.

I encounter with an input problem.

If i enter my input by one by one 
first '3' and first string and second string and third string.

There is no problem. But when I copy all input data and paste it readline() function reads all data. I thought it reads until '\n',

But it is not working.

Here is the Error Message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/SUUSER/Desktop/a.py", line 3, in <module>
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3\nasd\nfre\n345\n'
'3\nasd\nfre\n345\n'
```

It reads all data for (n)

But I just want to read 3.

How can i get it ?

Comment: That is very strange - the code works fine for me. How are you running the Python script?

Comment: Why not use `n = int(input())` there?

Comment: Same here, works for me too. Could you perhaps record the incident (Would be nice to see how you actually input the data, where, what console, OS etc.. getting an overview of the problem might help)

Comment: I also tried n = int(input()) but it's about copying and pasting all data to my interpretor(idle for python 3.3.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a platform issue. It appears your terminal, Python interpreter and paste source disagree on what an end of line is; by the presence of `"D:"` in the path, I guess it's a Windows platform, where newlines are traditionally stored as `'\r\n'` and entered as `'\r'` (carriage return). Python follows the C/Unix tradition of processing newlines as `'\n'` (line feed). With the wrong combination of terminal handling and clipboard contents, the `'\n'`  character will be passed like any other and not end a line. You can experiment with entering the newline styles manually; carriage return is Ctrl+M and line feed is Ctrl+J. Python also does have [support for different newline styles](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open); my guess is that in your particular terminal, `sys.stdin` is opened with `'\r'` newlines.

Comment: I use idle for python 3.3.2. So do i have to change settings or some kind of thing?

Comment: I imagine it wouldn't be broken if it was already known. To me it sounds like a bug in Idle; it apparently has its own implementations of sys.stdin etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244956/python-3-2-idle-vs-terminal

Answer (score 0):

int cannot convert \n into int value.

```
>>> print int('9\n')
9
>>> 
>>> print int('9\n3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9\n3'
```

remove sys.stdin.readline() like  following code:

```
import sys

n = 5 #length
for _ in range(n):
   s = input()
   print(int(s))
```

Comment: That is not the issue. `int('123\n')` works just fine; but notice how readline has returned multiple lines in one string in OP's transcript. That's what this question is about.

Comment: Yes this is not the problem