# .py file from Linux to Windows: is it going to just work?

Tags: python, linux, python-idle

I am using Python 2.7.5+ on my Linux Mint to write simple programs as .py files and running them in Konsole Terminal. These work fine on my computer, but I need to share them with a friend using Windows (IDLE I suppose) and wonder if these will work as they are without modification.

The programs start with the usual `#!/usr/bin/python`, you know.

Comment: They should work fine as long as you aren't using any platform-specific features.

Comment: Unless your code have Unix specific modules (select, dbus etc), you're fine on the running part. As for how to run the code by just invoking it is a bit different on the two platforms. `#!/python27/python` would need to be placed for the windows system to properly run it, altho that's mostly for IDLE or your text-editors run environment. I'd make sure `C:\Python27` is in your friends `%%PATH%%` on the windows machine and just instruct them to do `python yourcode.py`, that way both you and them can issue the same command. Or simply check out the link above for "double-click" functionality.

Comment: @Torxed The select module is not Unix-specific, it works on Windows too. (Although not everything in that module works on all platforms, like with the os module)

Comment: Start the script with `#!/usr/bin/env python` is better, as it may run in a virtual environment in Linux/UNIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Python code will work fine, but the shebang (#!) does nothing on Windows - only the filename extension (.py or .pyw) does. If you're handling filenames you'll want to use the functions in os.path. Line endings also differ, which means you'll want to tell [open()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) whether you're reading text or binary data. This also shows up in less adaptive text editors like Windows Notepad (and sadly [in Idle when pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707573/readline-reads-all-data-including-n)). [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is one capable text editor for Windows. There are also some [restrictions for multiprocessing in Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the script. Unless you use anything os-specific, you are golden.

In the standard library most of the modules are totally os-agnostic, and for the rest the rule of thumb is - "if it is possible to provide the same functionality across *nix and windows, it has probably been done".

Python actually makes it pretty easy to write portable programs. Even file paths manipulation is pretty portable if you do it right - `os.path.sep` instead of `'/'`, `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation etc.

Notable exceptions are

1. sockets - windows sockets are bit different
2. multiprocessing - windows does not have `fork()`, that may or may not be a problem.
3. Needless to say, things related to username, hostname and such.
4. `os` and `sys` are a mixed bag - you should read the compatibility notes in the docs.
5. Everything packaging and distribution-related.